# Implications of running script as argument to shell

Tags: linux, shellcode, bash

Context for the question is the following [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969879/is-dot-slash-a-command/969887#comment1553776_969893) on one of my answers:

> @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Prefacing a script name with /bin/bash or even just bash is also a common way to solve the lack of executable permissions on the script.

I've refuted with the obvious remarks that there's danger in giving a potentially malicious script ability to do what it wants while file itself doesn't have executable bit set, and obvious incompatibility of script written for say c-shell being run with bourne-like shell ( and syntax incompatibility among Bourne-like shells themselves ).  And the way I see it in hindsight, it's almost close to faulty advise of doing `curl somedomain/script.sh | bash`.

However, I'm curious if there are potentially more severe implications.  I know that merely [cat'ing a file](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/56307/121824) can be dangerous and [merely copy-pasting](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39118/121824) of a seemingly harmless script, but I'm curious if there's  anything not so obvious exists about running a script as argument to shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. If someone can get you to run a malicious script -- whether with `./scriptname` or with `bash scriptname` -- you're pretty much toast. Also, you shouldn't think of the execute permission as a protection against malware. Execute permission controls whether *you* are allowed to execute the script (via [`exec()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call)) and its relatives), not whether *it* is allowed to execute.

Comment: Yeah, for naive newbie user that doesn't make much difference, good point